# How can I run homebrew from an automation?

Tags: mac, automator, homebrew

[image]
This is my automation script, the commands work fine when I run them from Terminal.

Comment: The `$PATH` may not be configured correctly within Automator scripts—try explicitly using `/usr/local/bin/brew` instead of just `brew`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` passed to a **Run Shell Script** *action* in **Automator** by default is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

You need to include a `PATH` *statement* in the **Run Shell Script** *action* and or use *fully qualified pathnames* for any executables called.

That said, using three separate **Run Shell Script** *actions* in this use case makes the first one useless as *change directory* in the first **Run Shell Script** *action* has absolutely no bearing on the subsequent **Run Shell Script** *actions*.  You should work all the *commands* into a single **Run Shell Script** *action*.

In a single **Run Shell Script** *action* you could use the following example *shell script* *code*:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
cd "$HOME" || exit
brew update && brew upgrade
```

As coded, it does the following:

- The `PATH` *statement* includes `/usr/local/bin` where I'd assume `brew` is.
- If the `cd` *command* fails the *script* is stopped.
- `brew upgrade` is only executed if `brew update` succeeds .

---

That all said, I would just use **Terminal** normally to perform any `brew` *commands* so as to be able to see what is going on.